# Ordering list by many conditions using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have the code below that fills the list.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
    var p = new Person();
    if (i <= 10) p.Group = "A";
    else if (i <= 20) p.Group = "B";
    else p.Group = "C";
    p.Name = "Person " + i;
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        p.Age = 10;
    else
        p.Age = 20;
    people.Add(p);
}
```

Now I want to do sort in following order: All the people must be first that has Group "B" and must be in order by age. Then Rest of the people must be in order by Age, Group doesn't have to be in order. Here is the example:

```
Name   Group   Age
Person   B     10
Person   B     10
.....
Person   B     20
Person   B     20
Person   B     20
.....
//From here Group doesn't have to be in order.
Person   A     10
Person   A     10
.....
Person   C     10
Person   C     10
.....
Person   A     20
Person   A     20
Person   A     20
.....
Person   C     20
Person   C     20
Person   C     20
....
```

Can I do this with one linq query?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is a problem that the rest of groups would be ordered?

Comment: @Blau no it is not problem. I just need order rest of the people by age.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` to order `B` first, the *trick in here* is `false` always comes before `true`. Then you order by `Age`:

```
 var result = list.OrderBy(p => p.Group != "B")
                  .ThenBy(p => p.Age);
```